# how to fix angular 8 Bearer token request is unauthorized

Tags: javascript, jwt, angular8, bearer-token, unauthorized

When I request token key from angular8, unauthorized error is occurring. Which http header is required. Request body includes (username,password and grant_type) -

```
 login() {
    const header = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'No-Auth': 'True'
    });
    this.http.post(this.url, this.body, {headers: header}).subscribe( res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

Response Data -

```
{
"status": "SUCCESS",
"data": {
    "timestamp": "2019-09-21T04:49:25.021+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/daso/oauth/token"
  }
}
```

I use postman to check api, Postman use header Auth is Basic Auth (Username - vcs-api-client, Password - vcs-api-client)

```
{
"status": "SUCCESS",
"data": {
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.wwEHY-kavvgLbq9e9mdEsTrlM6rdGF7J4qs3IHhZN2Y",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.PZkjznQn_AAnPJWEsK8nkq7atzADayt6FIiakgqNi8Y",
    "expires_in": 7199,
    "scope": "read write trust",
    "userInformationResDto": {}
    "jti": "fefa6a6a-ff7d-442d-b00a-b349c096cc20"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested your api with other tools such as post man to ensure that the problem is not related to your server api?

Comment: Yes i use postman to check api, Postman use header Auth is Basic Auth (Username - vcs-api-client, Password - vcs-api-client)

Comment: how can i get bearer token key, my work flow is request token key from server and this token key to use new http header with Authorization : Bearer + this token key for login

Comment: `Postman use header Auth` then use that

Comment: Try 'Content-type': 'application/json' instead of 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', server might be expecting that type. Also, make sure your server has allowed CORS from all domain in dev phase.